# How to track changes in Cassandra table using Java

Tags: cassandra

I am just looking for a way to track changes in a table of Cassandra. I don't want to use a trigger. If any changes made I will immediately update my data source.

Do you have any idea how to implement this feature using Java?

Also is it possible to create a plugin for Cassandra? I did not find any good resource to create a plugin for Cassandra.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is Change Data Capture (CDC)
You can read more on [CDC in Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have read that CDS logs are not too reliable. reliability is key for me in this scenario.